# Passing a defined function to ODE solver

Tags: matlab

I have defined a function

```
function dy = toggle(t,y,p)
dy = zeros(2,1);
dy(1) = - y(1) + p(1)./(1+y(2).^p(2));
dy(2) = - y(2) + p(1)./(1+y(1).^p(3));
```

and saved it in an .m file with the same name as the function. In another file, caltoggle.m, I write:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@toggle,[0 100],[0.2,0.1],[],[3,2,2]);
```

When I run the script caltoggle.m I get the error:

```
??? [T,Y] = ode45(@
              |
Missing variable or function.

Error in ==> C:\MATLABR11\work\caltoggle.m
On line 1  ==> 

caltoggle
```

The above code is an example from a tutorial so should be right. My problem is in general I am not able to call a defined function.

Comment: Is your function called caltoggle or just toggle?

Comment: just toggle. "caltoggle.m" is the name of the second file in which I used ode45

Comment: Is the toggle file located in the same directory as caltoggle.m?

Comment: yes. and the problem is with any function I define (and I am sure it is correct), not just this.

Comment: Have you tried creating a handle (like h = @toggle) and just using h in the call to ode45?

Comment: yes and it did not work. I reinstalled Matlab and the problem persists.

Comment: @Aya You say you have trouble calling any function you define. Do you mean you cannot call any defined function or you just cannot use your functions in a call to `ode45` (or a similar function)? If it is the former, can you save a file called `mytest.m` which has in it `function mytest; disp('mytest is working')` - when calling `mytest` from the interpreter do you see `mytest is working`?

Comment: Hello Chris. Thank you for your help. I mean I cannot use "@myfunction". it does not work with me I do not know why. I tested your suggestion mytest.m and it worked, but this is different in that I did not need to write @mytest and that it does not include variables like y.

Answer (score 0):

If the other file is not in the same directory, you should add the directory to the path.
Try to write in Matlab:

> pathtool

Also, though it is probably not your case, if you name a file with a reserved word like "try", it can cause havoc.

Also, try to write

> which toggle

it might be insightful.

Comment: both are in the same path: C:\MATLABR11\work
i typed which toggle and it returned my only file toggle.m
does calling a function need to check something when I download Matlab? or probably is there another way to call a function in matlab 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

In the Matlab [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ode23.html) for the ODE solvers all of the examples pass as the first argument to `ode45` a function of 2 variables, not three like your function `toggle`. Can you change your `toggle` function to accept only two input arguments and see if that fixes the problem (as a first test just set `p(:)=1` or something similar)

Comment: I tried
    function dy = toggle(t,y)
    dy = zeros(2,1);
    dy(1) = - y(1) +1./(1+y(2));
    dy(2) = - y(2) +1./(1+y(1));    
then in another file named caltoggle.m I typed and saved:
    [T,Y] = ode45(@toggle,[0 100],[0.2,0.1],[]);
Then it returned:
    » ??? [T,Y] = ode45(@
                  |
    Missing variable or function.

    Error in ==> C:\MATLABR11\work\caltoggle.m
    On line 2  ==> 

    caltoggle

Comment: In the MATLAB interpreter, in the same directory as the file `toggle.m` what happens if you write `h = @toggle; h(1, [2,3])`?

Comment: I get:» h=@toggle;h(1,[2,3])
??? h=@
      |
Missing variable or function.

» .... I wander could this be a special property not necessarily included in my download? I just realize it is very important in my work now, although we did not use it in our introductory undergraduate course. I asked my friend to try it and she just told me she has the same issue. Al my matlab work is save in directory C:\MatlabR11\work and I open Matlab from a desktop shortcut.

Comment: @Aya [Function handles](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html) are part of the standard MATLAB library - they shoud be accessible on any installation of MATLAB. if you type `h=@toggle` and then print `h` do you get `ans = toggle` displayed? Alternatively you can type `isa(h, 'function_handle')` and you should get a true value printed.

Comment: @ Chris Thank you very much.. I will see this issue with my department